# Solving Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\beta > 0$, $0 < \gamma < 1$, and let $\tau$ be the first hitting time:
$$\tau = \inf\{t:t \geq 0, |W_t| = \pi /4\}$$
Solve the SDE in the random interval $0 \leq t \leq \tau$
$$dX_t = -(\beta + \dfrac{1}{2} \gamma^2)X_t dt + \gamma \sqrt{e^{-2 \beta t} -X_t^2}  dW_t$$
$$ X_0 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Remarks:
I believe the question is begging for some symmetry exploitation. Indeed, for fixed $\tau$, $W_{\tau}$ takes value $\pi/4$ w.p. 1/2 and $-\pi/4$ w.p. $1/2$. But I am having trouble understanding the connection between this interval, stopping times, and the solution process to a PDE.

My professor has only taught us multiplicative factor technique for solving SDE. I don't know how to deal with the random interval here. How does one even start this problem? I believe there is a trick which makes the solution short. Which techniques should I start with?

Comment: Can you run Ito's formula on $\log(X_t)$ and write the differential you get?

Comment: @Ian Sure, $d(log(X_t)) = - (\beta + \dfrac{\gamma^2 e^{-2 \beta t}}{2 X_t}) dt + \gamma \sqrt{e^{2 \beta t} - X_t^2} dW_t$

Comment: I meant to have it written entirely in terms of $Y_t=\log(X_t)$, but that still doesn't help. Hmm...

Comment: @Ian Any other suggestions? I added an additional remark about symmetry in my question.

Comment: @Ian And when you day "written entirely in terms of $Y_t = log(X_t)$", are you suggesting integrating both sides of $d(log(X_t)$ from $0$ to $t$, and then solving for $Y_t$? I just want to be clear on this (even though you say it is not helpful in solving the problem).

Comment: When it helps, you don't have to do any clever calculus, you just replace $X_t$ with $e^{Y_t}$ in the differential. But it doesn't help here.

Comment: The change of variable $$X_t=e^{-\beta t}\cos(Y_t)$$ and Itô's formula yield $$X_t=e^{-\beta t}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}4-\gamma W_t\right),$$ where we used the initial condition $X_0=\cos(\pi/4)$, as long as the argument in the square root in the SDE stays positive, that is, for every $t<\sigma$ with $$\sigma=\inf\{t>0\mid W_t\notin(-3\pi/(4\gamma),\pi/(4\gamma))\}.$$ Note that $\sigma<\tau$ with full probability since $0<\gamma<1$.

Comment: *Typo: $\sigma>\tau$ (which is why this fully solves the question).

Comment: @Did I am having trouble deriving the formula $X_t = e^{-\beta t} cos({\dfrac{\pi}{4} - \gamma W_t})$. Are you solving for $Y_t$ in your change of variables formula, and then using Ito's formula? Since $Y_t = f(t, X_t)$, we can use Ito's formula to write $dY_t$. But this is very complicated since $Y_t = e^{\beta t} arcos{X_t}$. I tried this and the result got very messy and not the same as yours. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If $X_t=e^{-\beta t}\cos(Y_t)$ with $\sin(Y_0)\gt0$ then, at least for small $t$, $$dX_t=-\beta e^{-\beta t}\cos(Y_t)-e^{-\beta t}\sin(Y_t)dY_t-\tfrac12e^{-\beta t}\cos(Y_t)d\langle Y\rangle_t,$$ thus, $$dX_t=-\beta X_tdY_t-\sqrt{e^{-2\beta t}-X_t^2}dY_t-\tfrac12X_td\langle Y\rangle_t.$$ By identification, if $dY_t=-\gamma dW_t$ and $d\langle Y\rangle_t=\gamma^2dt$ simultaneously, we are done. Happy surprise, $Y_t=Y_0-\gamma W_t$ fits these requirements, QED.

Comment: @Did This solution is very clever. How would I know to choose $X_t$ in that particular way? Is there a "cook-book" type solution to this problem? Where did your choice of $X_t$ come from?

Comment: No systematic approach but the term $\sqrt{e^{-2\beta t}-X_t^2}=e^{-\beta t}\sqrt{1-e^{2\beta t}X_t^2}$ is strongly suggestive.